# Long running MERGE statement

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I have the following MERGE statement taking very long (around 20-30 minutes). Environment is DB2 9.7 on LINUX. There are no other queries running on the database as it is dev environment.

```
MERGE INTO TEST.COMPANY cc
USING(SELECT c.COMPANY_ID COMPANY_ID, b.COUNTRY_ID COUNTRY_ID
      FROM COMPANY c, 
           BRNCH b
      WHERE b.branch_id IN (SELECT c.branch_id FROM COMPANY c)) a
ON(cc.COMPANY_ID=a.COMPANY_ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND a.COUNTRY_ID=11000 THEN
UPDATE SET cc.CTRY='US'
WHEN MATCHED AND a.COUNTRY_ID=11001 THEN
UPDATE SET cc.CTRY='CA';
```

TEST.COMPANY (86 COLUMNS)=1000 ROWS

- PK ON COMPANY_ID + COMPANY_REGION_ID

COMPANY (86 COLUMNS)=1.84 MILLION ROWS

- PK ON COMPANY_ID + COMPANY_REGION_ID

BRNCH (117 COLUMNS)=595

- PK ON BRANCH_ID

It took 12 minutes to execute this. I would appreciate any sql tuning help on this one. I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to join `COMPANY` and `BRNCH` in the `USING` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
MERGE INTO TEST.COMPANY cc
USING(SELECT c.COMPANY_ID COMPANY_ID, b.COUNTRY_ID COUNTRY_ID
      FROM COMPANY c 
           INNER JOIN 
           BRNCH b
           ON b.branch_id = c.branch_id) a
ON(cc.COMPANY_ID=a.COMPANY_ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND a.COUNTRY_ID=11000 THEN
UPDATE SET cc.CTRY='US'
WHEN MATCHED AND a.COUNTRY_ID=11001 THEN
UPDATE SET cc.CTRY='CA';
```

Comment: I am awfully stunned. This made a world's difference and ran in 5 seconds. My mind is baffled.